# NDSolve output - ParametricPlot not plotting

Tags: differential-equations

I cannot understand why I cannot reproduce an example given in the NDSolve command help.

Namely I would like to plot the steepest ascent path on the surface $z = x^2-y^2$, starting from the point $(0,-1)$. I try to solve the system of differential equations for the gradient flow

```
  s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 2*x[t], y'[t] == -2*y[t], x[0] == 0, 
   y[0] == -1}, {x, y}, {t, 20}]
```

but when I issue the command, as in the command help

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 20}]
```

the axes appear, but not the expected plot, a segment from $(-1,0)$ to $(0,0)$, thanks for any hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a `PlotRange` seems to work for me:

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s],
 {t, 0, 20},
 ImageSize -> 400,
 PlotRange -> {-2, 2},
 PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3]
]
```

[image: Parametric plot with plot range specified.]

Comment: I would love to understand why Plot Range is not needed in the NDSolve command help..

Comment: @Smerdjakov I don't think `PlotRange` is needed in general. I think it might be just because the ratio of line width to height is 0:1 and `ParametricPlot` isn't expecting that? I'm not totally sure though, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Using the setup of OP, you can visualize curve of steepest ascent from {0.-1,-1}:

```
s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 2*x[t], y'[t] == -2*y[t], x[0] == 0, 
    y[0] == -1}, {x, y}, {t, 20}];

f[x_, y_] := x^2 - y^2
g[a_, b_] := Grad[z - f[x, y], {x, y, z}] /. {x -> a, y -> b}
pl = g[0, -1] . {x, y + 1, z + 1};
Show[
 Plot3D[{x^2 - y^2, -(pl - z)}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.7], Opacity[0.2]}],
 ParametricPlot3D[{x[t], y[t], f[x[t], y[t]]} /. s, {t, 0, 20}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Graphics3D[{Arrow[{{0, -1, f[0, -1]}, {0, -1, f[0, -1]} + 
      0.5 g[0, -1]}], Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[{0, -1, -1}]}], 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, Background -> Black, AxesStyle -> Yellow]
```

[image]